# Return only if a number of results with certain conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql, nested, subquery

I've been looking at this for hours and can't quite seem to get it right.
I have a table with 3 columns.

```
AsOfDate                      database_id    mirroring_state_desc
2014-10-14 09:46:25.083           7             SUSPENDED
2014-10-14 09:47:09.340           7             SUSPENDED
2014-10-14 09:47:10.767           7             SUSPENDED
2014-10-14 09:47:11.987           7             SUSPENDED
2014-10-14 12:34:23.917           7             SUSPENDED
2014-10-14 12:40:11.337           7             SUSPENDED
```

Basically I'm putting together a sp and in this sp an email will be sent if certain conditions are met.  The conditions in this instance are if there are 3 or more of the above rows for distinct database_id that are less than an hour old.  So if this criteria is not met nothing should be returned.

This is what I've tried.

```
IF EXISTS (select distinct top (@MirroringStatusViolationCountForAlert) AsOfDate
            from dbo.U_MirroringStatus
            WHERE [AsOfDate] >= dateadd(minute, -60, getdate()))

IF EXISTS (select distinct top 3 AsofDate
from dbo.U_MirroringStatus
WHERE [AsOfDate] >= dateadd(minute, -60, getdate()) IN
    (select AsofDate from dbo.U_MirroringStatus
      GROUP BY AsOfDate HAVING COUNT(*)>=3))
```

Any help would be really appreciated as the longer I look at this the more confused I am getting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option ..

```
declare @t table (AsOfDate datetime, database_id int, mirroring_state_desc varchar(20))

insert into @t(AsOfDate, database_id, mirroring_state_desc)
select 
'2014-10-14 08:46:25.083', 7, 'SUSPENDED'
union all select
'2014-10-14 10:47:09.340',           7,             'SUSPENDED'
union all select
'2014-10-14 10:47:10.767',           7,             'SUSPENDED'
union all select
'2014-10-14 10:47:11.987',           7,             'SUSPENDED'
union all select
'2014-10-13 12:34:23.917',           7,             'SUSPENDED'
union all select
'2014-10-13 12:40:11.337',           7,             'SUSPENDED'

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @t
    WHERE AsOfDate >= dateadd(minute, -60, getdate())
    GROUP BY database_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
    )
    print 'Has 3 or more'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @count int = 3
if exists (
            Select  '*' 
            from    dbo.U_MirroringStatus a
            where   @count >= (Select   count(AsOfDate) 
                                from    dbo.U_MirroringStatus b
                                where   [b.AsOfDate] >= dateadd(minute, -60, getdate())
                                and     a.database_id  = b.database_id 
                                )
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TestStatus') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TestStatus
GO

CREATE TABLE TestStatus (
    AsOfDate DATETIME,
    database_id INT,
    mirroring_state_desc NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO TestStatus VALUES 
    ('2014-10-14 04:46:25.083',7,'SUSPENDED'),
    ('2014-10-14 04:47:09.340',7,'SUSPENDED'),
    ('2014-10-14 04:47:10.767',7,'SUSPENDED'),
    ('2014-10-14 09:47:11.987',7,'SUSPENDED'),
    ('2014-10-14 12:34:23.917',7,'SUSPENDED')



IF (SELECT COUNT(database_id) FROM TestStatus WHERE DATEDIFF(hour,AsOfDate,GETDATE()) > 1) > 3
PRINT 'There are more than 3 results which are older than an hour'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this in your query:

```
IF EXISTS (
 SELECT top 3 database_id
    FROM dbo.U_MirroringStatus
    WHERE (AsOfDate] >= dateadd(minute, -60, getdate())
    GROUP BY database_id
    HAVING COUNT(*)>=3
)
```